# adding the contract value but still not changed

Tags: web3js, contract-design

I am using web3 1.0 and testrpc, The following is my contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract LocalEthereum {

    event Created(bytes32 _tradeHash);
    uint32 value = 0;

    function addValue()  external {

        value = value + 1;
        Created(0x01);
    }

    function getValue()  returns (uint)  {

        return value;
    }
}
```

This is the js application.

```
   createValue(account){
      console.log('createEscrow');
      this.escrowContract.methods.addValue().send({from: account,gas:210000,gasPrice:5000000000})
                      .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
                          console.log('hash',hash);
                      })
                      .on('receipt', function(receipt){
                          console.log('receipt',receipt);
                      })
                      .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
                          console.log('confirmation',confirmationNumber);
                      })
                      .on('error', console.error);

  }



  this.escrowContract.methods.getValue().call({from: account})
                    .then(function(result){
                        console.log('getTestValue',result);
                    });
```

I have used createValue() multiple times, so the expected results is the **value variable** in the contract will be non-zero, however when calling the **getValue()** method, it is still zero value.

what is the problem?

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

it is wield that I changed the value to 10 instead of 0, but the method still return 0.

this.escrowContract.methods.getValue().call({from: account})
                    .then(function(result){
                        console.log('getTestValue',result);
                    });

this is the testrpc console output of transcation and call method,

eth_sendRawTransaction

```
  Transaction: 0x0f22da3b8ee8bc286afab370dc0b38734e4c51eda2eb6d81176de8ac0a980fd8
  Gas usage: 21272
  Block Number: 8
  Block Time: Tue Jan 02 2018 12:26:22 GMT+0000 (GMT)

eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_call
```

everything seems to be normal.

Answer (score 0):

The solidity works fine, I'm guessing you're just calling the whole js application at once.

Try throwing it after you get a success:

```
   createValue(account){
      console.log('createEscrow');
      this.escrowContract.methods.addValue().send({from: account,gas:210000,gasPrice:5000000000})
                      .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
                          console.log('hash',hash);
                      })
                      .on('receipt', function(receipt){
                          console.log('receipt',receipt);

                    this.escrowContract.methods.getValue().call({from: account})
                    .then(function(result){
                        console.log('getTestValue',result);
                    });
                      })
                      .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
                          console.log('confirmation',confirmationNumber);
                      })
                      .on('error', console.error);

  }
```

If this isn't the issue and you're calling it separately, I would just check to make sure it's going through properly on the testrpc

Comment: I am calling them separately one by one actually. I have used your method, still not working.  I have checked my testrpc, all the transactions and calls are being recorded but js application receives zero.

Comment: So the receipt on javascript is not logging correctly?  Does a basic console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(account)) work?

Comment: the logging is correct in the testrpc console, it outputs the transaction receipt as well as the call, but calling doesn't return the data correctly.